# Construct ffmpeg command to do picture-in-picture for part of a video

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I run a programming hobbyist users' group, and I've started to video-record the talks given each time we meet.  I'm trying to construct an ffmpeg command to take two video input streams, one a screen capture and the other of a speaker, and combine them into one video with picture-in-picture, taking the audio from the speaker video.  I have basic picture-in-picture working in a simple ffmpeg command, but I want to be able to specify that the beginning and end of the video show just the speaker, while the middle is picture-in-picture with the speaker in the upper right-hand corner.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ffmpeg \
  -ss 22 \
  -i "capture.mp4" \
  -ss 32 \
  -i "speaker.mov" \
  -filter_complex "[1] split=3[s1][s2][s3]; [s1] trim=0:10, scale=1920x1080 [prefix]; [s2] trim=10:, scale=iw/5:ih/5 [pip]; [s3] trim=0:0, scale=1920x1080 [suffix]; [0] copy [c]; [c][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0 [body]; [prefix][body][suffix] concat=n=3 [out]" \
  -map "[out]" \
  -profile:v baseline \
  -level 3.0 \
  -b:v 440k \
  -vcodec libx264 \
  -acodec copy \
  -y \
  ffmpeg-test.mov
```

Right now, there are two problems:

- no sound appears in the output
- in the picture-in-picture section, the speaker's motion isn't smooth; the video jumps as if he had been sampled every half second even though the speaker video is at 29.97 fps.  (Perhaps the problem is that it's matching the capture frame rate, which is 5 fps.)

I'm trying to do this in just one command in order to make the processing as quick as possible.

Is there any way to accomplish this with ffmpeg?  It would really help me to be able to automate this process as much as possible.

Thanks.

EDIT: Per LordNeckbeard's request, here is the full console output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'capture.mp4':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
creation_time   : 2015-11-09 17:29:41
  Duration: 01:42:51.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 115 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 4 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : AAC stream handler
Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 109 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : Citrix h264 stream handler
  encoder         : AVC Coding
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'speaker.mov':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2015-11-09 21:17:52
  Duration: 00:59:57.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7264 kb/s
Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(bt709), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 5724 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-11-09 21:17:52
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  encoder         : AVCHD 1080i60
  timecode        : 00:00:00;00
Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-11-09 21:17:52
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #1:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-11-09 21:17:52
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  timecode        : 00:00:00;00
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] frame MB size (120x68) > level limit (1620)
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] DPB size (1 frames, 8160 mbs) > level limit (0 frames, 8100 mbs)
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] MB rate (244555) > level limit (40500)
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] 264 - core 148 r2601 a0cd7d3 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=440 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to 'cli-ffmpeg-test.mov':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 440 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> copy
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> split
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=184483 fps=117 q=-1.0 Lsize=  256071kB time=01:42:35.58 bitrate= 340.8kbits/s dup=153456 drop=0    
video:255343kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.285118%
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] frame I:779   Avg QP: 5.70  size:181781
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] frame P:183704 Avg QP:10.00  size:   652
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] mb I  I16..4: 77.8%  0.0% 22.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.4%  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] final ratefactor: 13.35
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 21.1% 28.5% 19.4% inter: 0.2% 0.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 74% 23%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 26% 15%  4%  4%  5%  4%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 68% 20% 10%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f99a980de00] kb/s:339.82
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from your command. It will provide information necessary to provide an answer.

Comment: I've added the console output in an edit.  Thanks.

Comment: Aha!  I fixed the second problem by replacing "[0] copy [c]" with "[0] fps=fps=29.97 [c]".  Now the picture-in-picture video is not jumpy.

But I still have no audio.

Comment: Any advice on the audio?

Comment: You disabled the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior by adding `-map "[out]"`, so you need to add another one for the audio: `-map 1:a`.

Comment: Why are you using the `copy` filter? Also, your second (`trim=10:`) and third (`trim=0:0`) trim durations from your command don't make sense to me. What times do you want the PiP to appear?

Comment: I was using <copy> as a placeholder.  See my comment above, where I replaced it with <fps> to eliminate the jumpiness.

Comment: The "10:" is used for the picture-in-picture segment and is a complement to the "0:10" used before PIP starts.  I used "0:0" for the last segment because, in this particular case, there's enough screen capture to last through the end of the speaker video, so there's no need for a speaker-only section.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you!  With <-map 1:a> I now have audio.  However, I'm getting lots of worrisome messages, e.g. these:

[Parsed_overlay_8 @ 0x7f9a43c26920] [framesync @ 0x7f9a43c269e8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 31 times
[Parsed_overlay_8 @ 0x7f9a43c26920] [framesync @ 0x7f9a43c269e8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 44 times
[Parsed_overlay_8 @ 0x7f9a43c26920] [framesync @ 0x7f9a43c269e8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 44 times
[Parsed_overlay_8 @ 0x7f9a43c26920] [framesync @ 0x7f9a43c269e8]

Comment: If the output looks fine, ignore them.

Comment: Do you know what they mean?  I don't want to have to listen to the whole hour carefully just to be sure.  Thanks.